# node get the source code from url and display

Tags: jquery, node.js, node-webkit, node-modules, domparser

I am using node-webkit to create an application. I need to get the webpage from the url and display it.

I have tried using `request` module. it gets the source code content properly. but while displaying it, the css files and images are not displayed.

I cant use iframes because websites like `http://www.flipkart.com` cannot be loaded into iframes and it replaces the whole page.

I cant use php here..

Is there any proper dom parser in jquery??

(Is there any way to display the css and images correctly so that i can continue using request module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load external sites which check if they are the main window, nw.js has an attribute you can place on an iframe to fool the content into thinking it is the top/main frame: `nwfaketop`. This removes access to `window.parent` and `window.top`.

Also, if you are loading external content you may want to combine this with `nwdisable`, which disables Node within the iframe.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iframe test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="600" height="600" src="http://www.flipkart.com" nwdisable nwfaketop></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

More information can be found in the nw.js documentation: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Mini-browser-in-iframe